# "type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'" even with "import datetime"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I'm getting `type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'` errors on AppEngine, complaining about the datetime type, but my import is `import datetime`. There *are* `from datetime import datetime` in *other* files, but I don't think that should affect this file?

There's no 'accidental' re-imports, I've checked. I've checked my AppEngine logs, and it only started happening 2 days ago.

I'm using 2.7 runtime.

EDIT: Here's the line that's causing the error (note that I'm using `import datetime`, NOT `from datetime import datetime`)

```
task.due_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p')
```

EDIT: Stack trace

```
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~wmphighrise/1.373696587983821954/myapp/handler/decorators.py", line 22, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~wmphighrise/1.373696587983821954/myapp/handler/api/main.py", line 1343, in post
    task.due_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p')
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

EDIT 3: Some debugging

Note: `import datetime` is at the top

```
#1st attempt
import datetime
class MyHandler():
  def get(self):
    logging.info(datetime) # => "<type 'datetime.datetime'>"

#2nd attempt
import datetime
class MyHandler():
  def get(self):
    import datetime  # explicitly re-import the module
    logging.info(datetime) # => "<module 'datetime' (built-in)>"

#3rd attempt
import datetime
class MyHandler():
  def get(self):
    logging.info(datetime) # => Throws UnboundLocalError: local variable 'datetime' referenced before assignment
                           # Is this normal? This is new to me.
    import datetime
    logging.info(datetime)

#4th attempt
import datetime
logging.info(datetime) # => "<module 'datetime' (built-in)>"
class MyHandler():
  def get(self):
    logging.info(datetime) # => "<type 'datetime.datetime'>"
```

Is there a way for a variable to be redefined *outside* the current file or module? Because I've looked and looked at this file and there's no redefining at all.

EDIT 4:

I've `ack`'d `"datetime ="`, `"datetime="`, `"datetime.datetime ="` and `"datetime.datetime="`, but there's no results that does reassigning. I've checked my git log for the last 2 days, and there's no changes that could've introduced it

Comment: There is no `datetime.datetime.datetime`. You've gone one layer too deep in your inception.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've imported the `datetime` module. There should be a `datetime.datetime` type class in it.

Comment: there is, but you're trying to call `datetime` on a `datetime.datetime` object. I count 3 :)

Comment: The error says 'datetime.datetime' does not have 'datetime', because it doesn't. You just need 'datetime.datetime'.

Comment: Are your edits all in one module? Or different versions?

Comment: All in one module/file. Just tried it 3 times.

Comment: Ok you have something odd going on, and we need to see real code.  Specifically attempt 3 is not possible with normal python code and there is no way 4th attempt could do that either.

Comment: I also don't believe it could possiblly be the general appengine runtime otherwise all my applications would have that problem too ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The code you've included works for me, so the problem is likely that you've shadowed the `datetime` module with a `datetime.datetime` object called `datetime`. No seriously, I meant to type all that.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime = datetime.datetime.now()  # waves goodbye to datetime module!
>>> task.due_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: I wish it was that. I've reviewed my code, and there's no re-assigning `datetime`.

Comment: Can you `print datetime` before the line in question?

Comment: Updated OP with print statements.

Comment: Is there a way for a variable to redefined *outside* the file?

Comment: yes. everything importing `datetime` is accessing the same module. you could theoretically have a call `datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()` made from a different module

Comment: sorry, just realized you don't get notified of comments here unless i include @john2x

Comment: Ok, I've `ack`d `"datetime ="`, `"datetime="`, `"datetime.datetime ="` and `"datetime.datetime="`, but there's no results that does reassigning. I've checked my git log for the last 2 days, and there's no changes that could've introduced it. (It's only happened since 2 days ago)

Comment: I'm afraid I have no further ideas as to where the problem originated. I can explain why you get the error, but couldn't venture a further guess what broke it. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking about the `UnboundLocalError` error in the following code snippet. Am I right?

```
#3rd attempt
import datetime
class MyHandler():
    def get(self):
        logging.info(datetime) # => Throws UnboundLocalError: local variable 'datetime' referenced before assignment
                           # Is this normal? This is new to me.
        import datetime
        logging.info(datetime)
```

If so, the error is quite obvious. Two things you should understand:

1. All namespace changes (assignment,del,import,def,class) happen in the **local scope**(i.e. in the current scope in which the namespace-changing code executes)
2. import X imports the module X, and creates a reference to that module in the current namespace. i.e. `import` changes namespace.

Though name `datetime` did refer to the same object(module datetime) before and after you call `import datetime` in function `get`, but those two `datetime` are in different scope(first one global, second one local).

Once Python detect that **there is a name(in your case "datetime") in local scope**, it will raise error if you use the name before your **local name binding**.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def get():
        print(dir())

>>> get()
[]
>>> def get():
        import datetime
        print(dir())

>>> get()
['datetime']
>>>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've always gotten a chuckle out of saying `datetime.datetime`, but you've taken it even further and asked python for `datetime.datetime` for it's attribute `datetime`. :D

And of course, python doesn't have a `datetime.datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to convert a custom date to datetime and this worked for me:

```
end_date = '2025-12-31'
end_date = datetime(2025, 12, 31)
end_date= end_date.date()
```